# Spring Data Jpa - scans for files in tests folder

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring Data JPA and it's strange but it tries to scan (during deploy) test files, which causes an error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.runner.RunWith
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1678)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1523)
...
WARN : org.springframework.core.type.classreading.AnnotationAttributesReadingVisitor - Failed to classload      type while reading annotation metadata. This is a non-fatal error, but certain annotation metadata may be     unavailable.
```

The classnotfoundexception is because test dependencies are in "test" scope in maven.

But my question is, why it is scanning test folder? (/src/main/test).

The context configuration is as follows:

```
 <jpa:repositories base-package="com.domain.repository" />
```

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong? My .classpath content is as follows:

```
<classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/java"/>
<classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/resources"/>
<classpathentry kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/java"/>
<classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/resources"/>
...
```

I really appreciate your help with this.

Comment: I'm having this same issue in my project, with spring 3.1.1. Have you found your way around it?

Answer (score 2):

> But my question is, **why it is scanning test folder? (/src/main/test)**.
>
> The context configuration is as follows:
>
> `<jpa:repositories base-package="com.domain.repository" />`

To be precise, I don't think Spring is scanning this folder - it is your source folder after all. It's only looking at the deployed package structure and my suspicion would be that the cause of the problem has something to do with that.

I encountered the same problem but it was caused by an erroneous deployment configuration in Eclipse rather than something specific to Spring. I had Eclipse configured to deploy my test classes in `src/test/java` to the target deployment package so all the test files (that of course had corresponding package structures) where present when I started the server. However, judging by the `.classpath` snippet you've posted, I see you are explicitly excluding them from being deployed.

Nevertheless, there are other ways that class files can creep into your deployment. Have you been able to verify that the test classes are in fact not present in the deployed package? Could they be being synched there by some other process that you've set up (*FileSynch* plugin maybe)?

Also, do you have any other Spring context files with configurations to scan other base packages?

You might add some more details about your Eclipse configuration and how you're deploying to your test server to help solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug "pseudo feature" in Spring:

https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-9233

that warns you when it can't find the class for an annotation at run-time, even if your application is pretty much OK.